# Delete item in form and persist to the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a delete button in my form that looks like this:

```
%td  
  %button.btn.btn-default{class: "delete-btn", "data-id" =>booking.id} Delete
```

How should I write my javascript to make it delete the row in the table when the Delete button is clicked?

Basically, how do I modify this in my application.js file

```
$(".delete-btn").on("click", function(e) {
        var bkId = $(e.target).data("id");
        //line to delete it from my form and the db
    });
```

Previously, I had this in my html form to perform the deletion

```
'Delete', booking, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

**Please can someone show me how the .js/ajax equivalent would be?**

I have developed this code so far (it executes but i keep getting my error message):

```
$(".delete-btn").on("click", function(e) {
        var bkId = $(e.target).data("id");
        $.ajax("/bookings", {
            data: {
                booking: {
                    id: bkId
                }
            },
            method: "DELETE"

        }).done(function(resp){
            window.location = location.href;
        }).fail(function(resp){
            console.log("Error. Unable to delete");
            alert("Error. Unable to delete this booking");
        })
    });
```

Comment: You would need to use ajax to send data to server. It's not hard to find tutorils for this

Comment: I have searched online before posting this, but haven't figured out the syntax yet, please can you help?

Comment: You have the item id....you need to send that to server with ajax.... how to use ajax is easy to find in web searches and in the jQuery API. Also requires a server script to receive and process request

Comment: i see, i developed the above ajax command so far, can you advise how to correct it? Somehow it's not executing, the error message keeps showing up.

Comment: not common to nest object like that...is server expecting nested data? Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for all clues related to the actual request in order to isolate server vs client issues

Comment: How about using jQuery with css. You can make the element 'display:none;' $('button').click(function(){  $('element').css('display', 'none');   });

Comment: will that result in just the front end not displaying that id? My intent is to do that and also delete the record from my db.

Comment: Ok. Within the same click function you can call ajax file that deletes w.e id you pass to it.

Comment: like my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy to accomplish this:

```
%td= link_to 'Delete', booking, :method => :delete, class: "btn btn-danger"
```

Yet, I'm looking for the more complicated one which involves modifying my application.js (see above) to develop my understanding of how the communication between front and back end works.